# Copy float2 values back from GPU in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu

I would like to copy float2 values back to CPU. The results are correct in GPU side but some how the results are incorrect in CPU side. Can someone please help me

GPU code

```
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_printf : enable
__kernel void matM(__global float* input, int width, int height, __global float2* output){    
    int X = get_global_id(0);
    float2  V;  
    V.x = input [X];
    V.y = input [X];
    output[X] = V;  
    printf("%f\t %f\n",output[X].x,output[X].y);
  }
```

CPU code

```
output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float2) * wid*ht, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueReadBuffer( commands, output,CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float2) * wid *ht, results, 0, NULL, NULL );
```

The `printf` inside GPU kernel prints correct results but the host side results are incorrect.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Could we see the code where you are actually calling the code?  Perhaps you did not set an argument correctly or some such.

Comment: how do you allocate variable to hold data from GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cl_float2` datatype can be used on host side to access `float2` data,
but my problem was something else.

There was a mismatch in global ids,
I had two global ids and in line 3 should have been `int X = get_global_id(0) + get_global_id(1)`.